# PostgreSQL 14 and Unique Index Issue

Tags: postgresql

I have a database I am importing and it has a unique index for a field that is null.   In PostgreSQL 13 it was not an issue but in 14 it now longer allows the import as null is no longer null but a value.

Is there a setting where null is treated like it should be instead of as a value?

Comment: Yes, there's a setting. The PostgreSQL guys added it in v14 and it now prevent nulls collisions. It's possible to disable it. Let me check...

Comment: I was wrong. The new feature (that I personally don't like) will be present in PostgreSQL 15 and adds the clause `NULLS [NOT] DISTINCT` to the `CREATE INDEX` statement. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createindex.html If you are using PostgreSQL 14 then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I see that about 15.    Post upgrading to 14.5 it now prevents my import.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior has not changed in PostgreSQL v14. If the import doesn't work in the database, the only possible explanation is that you have defined the column `NOT NULL` in one database, but not in the other one (or used a similar check constraint).

PostgreSQL v15 introduces this standard conforming additional clause for unique constraints:

```
UNIQUE NULLS [NOT] DISTINCT
```

If you define a unique constraint with `NULLS NOT DISTINCT` in v15, it will behave differently from prior versions. However, the default is still `UNIQUE NULLS DISTINCT`.

Comment: In the schema that field is set to nullable.... in 13 it worked (my import from Oracle) in 14.5 it no longer works.   

There must be a setting where null is not treated as a value.

`sender_id character varying(10) NULL`

Comment: No, there is no such setting. Perhaps it is not a NULL value after all. Please edit the question and add a sequence of SQL statements that reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are no constraints setup for this table yet.

Comment: The question is valid and I will work up a test example of the breaking change when I upgraded to 14.5

Comment: Claiming that the question is valid doesn't make a difference. I am not saying that is is invalid, I am saying that it is incomplete. It is up to you to prove that what you say really happens by providing a reproducible test case. Otherwise, how shall we reproduce the problem and answer your question?

Comment: I'm using a 3rd party tool that takes data from various databases and pushes them into Postgres.      I think it's doing some translation off null to be '' or something.

Comment: when I do `where sender_id is not null` in psql it returns the first record from the imported table.   If I do insert into and do not include sender_id, I can do `where sender_id is null` and those newly inserted records are returned.

Comment: Ok, just trying to figure out why something is not working at worked before upgrading to 14.5.    Not sure how to reproduce a test case.   Will update once I know something.

Thanks for looking at my question, sorry if it's incomplete / gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

when I query the table, the null values are being set as '' during the import, so it fails after the first row.    Not sure what changed (other than upgrading to 14.5).  Going to reach out to the importer company, I can insert multiple null values so somethings up on their end.

Comment: Confirmed the import tool I was using has two options when importing data: via inserts or via copy.    The via inserts replaces nulls with '', the via copy does not change the values of null.    Not sure why I didn't notice this.   So it has nothing to do with PostgreSQL but that tool.